# Showing extra rows in database after importing to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, database

I'm building a program that needs the following features:

- Import an Excel file into database -- Check
- Avoid duplicates --- working on it
- Ignore some rows that are in the header of the Excel file and the bottom --- that's what I want to ask you guys

Here's my code

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO,IMEX=1;\"";

    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
    excelConnection.Open();

    DataTable schema = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    string sheetName = schema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + sheetName + "]", excelConnection);
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
    {
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(0,0);
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(1,1);
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(2,2);
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(3,3);
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Dados";

        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    }

    excelConnection.Close();
}
```

And what I'm struggling is that I need to my code to find the columns in the excel and ignore the rows that I don't need...

I thought that this lines were enough for the job  :

```
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(0,0);
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(1,1);
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(2,2);
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(3,3);
sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Dados";
```

Here's the table that I want to import :

[image: Excel tables]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would help answering your question to know the structure of the table you're trying to import (you can anonymize the cells of course, but it should be detailed enough that one can see the header, footer and data area).

Comment: You've had enough duplicate posts deleted by now Pedro/OverKnown/Holmes, to know what you need to do here. Making duplicate accounts to avoid warnings, restrictions, etc, enforced by the site/mods is against the rules. To avoid the headers, then just specify your document has headers in your connection string (Change `HDR=NO` to `HRD=YES`). If you want to start at row 14 (which should be in your qusetion) change your `SELECT` to `"Select * from [" + sheetName + ":$A14:S]"` where `A` and `S` are the columns you want to import. If you want to ignore blank cells, add a `WHERE`.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks Larnu! But I Can't identify the cell, I have to localize the columns cause imagine if the costumer wants to put the same table schema but with more cell at beggining ?

Comment: If you can't standardise the worksheet, how can you hope to standardise the code? If you can't do one, you can do the other. How do *you* know when the header starts, if the header could literally be anywhere? If you can't answer that question, then neither can anyone else here.

Comment: @Larnu Tried already the ``` HDR =NO``` to ``` HDR =YES```` Nothing happened

Comment: Because you're importing the whole sheet and row A doesn't have Headers (it's only got a single cell with a value by the looks of it); you need to import where your data is which isn't starting at row 1; Like I explained in the above comment.

Comment: @Larnu Obviously The header will start always in cell A:1 but It can end in different cell than cell 14

Comment: *"The header will start always in cell A:1"* It doesn't in your image; so either your image isn't representative of your data, or the above statement is false.

Comment: A1 = BPI Net Empresas

Comment: The table that I want to import starts at A:15. I want to avoid the first 15 rows... Basically I want to avoid rows until my program match the excel columns with the database columns

Comment: That isn't a header, that's a merged cell, with what I assume is the title of the document. Your first **header** is about 10 cells down (hard to tell without borders) with the value  "Data Mov.", then you have "Data Valor" and then a I can't type on a UK keyboard. *Those* are your headers.

Comment: What I was hoping to see is, how the table is embedded in Excel - a screen shot with the Excel cell coordinates.

Comment: *"The table that I want to import starts at A:15. I want to avoid the first 15 rows."* I've already answered that: *"If you want to start at row 14 (which should be in your qusetion) change your `SELECT` to "`Select * from [" + sheetName + ":$A14:S]`"*"

Comment: @Larnu wow Ok my bad, I want to avoid the merged cells yeah until my program identifies the excel heards

Comment: @Larnu I appreciate your comment but I can't specify the cells where my program starts to read, cause the columns can be in a different cell... And I know that it's possible to read all rows until you got the header but I don't know how

Comment: Then I go back to my other statement *"If you want to start at row 14 (which should be in your qusetion) change your SELECT to "Select * from [" + sheetName + ":$A14:S]"*. Sounds like, to me, you should upload the file, all as text, to your RDBMS, and then get the RDBMS to do the work. So instead of ETL, do ELT; which is what you've been offered in your other posts, on your other (now deleted) accounts and rejected for *reasons*. Use the tools you have at hand, and SQL Server will be far better at stopping duplicates and handling this.

Comment: If you must use C# to find the headers, you will need to write C# code to read each row, in the Excel document, row by row, column by column, until it finds a header column, and then doesn't any more (which honestly, you're on your own for, as SO isn't a free coding service, and that's a huge things for someone to ask to write for you).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks you anyway! Doing the ELT what my program will do? I still need to Do the Select * from [" + sheetName + ":$A14:S]"?

Comment: Yes, so you'll import everything into the database (to a staging table), and then use SQL Server to do the transformation (to the production table).

Comment: @Larnu So How I will Pass to ELT instead of ETL?~

Comment: Huh? I was describing the process you're going to do instead. Instead of an [ETL](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=define%3A+ETL) process, you'll do an ELT. it's up to you to do the rest of the work though. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with fluctuating source files is tricky. Maybe try loading the file as a whole into a raw table and then after loading the table call a proc to only move the columns that match complete row to your prod or final table. For example, only select from raw where Data Mov, Data Valor, Descricao do Movimento, and Valor em EUR are not null. If needed you could add more validation if needed, like checking the first two columns for date format and the last column for a numeric value. I just think it might be easier to do it in SQL than in .NET code.